Different behavior of right-click vs ctrl-click in MacOS (triggered by QInputDialog), and it partially freezes pyside6
I am working on this pyside6 project where the goal is for users to load some data, then draw a polygon onto them as "gate". The program will later provide analysis of data points inside the gate. I encountered this wired behavior on MacOS.
(The example is a reduced version that only draws a line) To recreate this behavior, you will need to

click "Draw polygon" button, and now move cursor to the plotting area.
You can either left click or Right click to confirm the line (exactly the same code). A warning dialog will show.
If you use right click in the previous step, some of the UI will be frozen, including the "Load new random data" button. But left click is absolutely OK.
And most interestingly, if you use "ctrl + click" in step 2, the ui will function as expected.

Things that I have tried / other related information:

This bug is likely caused by the warning dialog (QDialog class also cause the bug). If I skip that dialog (around line 77 in the code) the bug goes away.
When the UI freezes, you can unfreeze it by right click in the plotting area to call out a context memu.
This is a MacOS specific bug, as the same code (non-reduced version), works as intended on windows and linux. It happens on almost (?) all Mac I have tried.
I have a similar version of code with pyqt5, and it has the same bug.

The code is rather long, as it was reduced from a large project. I have tried my best to reduce it.
import sys

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg import FigureCanvasQTAgg

import numpy as np
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')

class mainUi(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        # init and setup UI
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(800, 800)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget, )

        self.loadDataPB = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Load new random data', self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.loadDataPB, 0, 0)

        self.addGatePB = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Draw polygon', self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.addGatePB, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.mpl_canvas = plotCanvas()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.mpl_canvas, 1, 0, 1, 2)

        self.action1 = QtGui.QAction('action 1')
        self.mpl_canvas.addActions([self.action1])
        self.mpl_canvas.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ActionsContextMenu)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        # connect necessary signals
        self.loadDataPB.clicked.connect(self.draw_figure)
        self.addGatePB.clicked.connect(self.handle_draw_polygon)

        # saved polygon
        self.polygon = None
        self.draw_figure()


    # the centre handler for updating the figure.
    def draw_figure(self):
        # this function is used to process info for the canvas to redraw
        mock_data = np.array([10**np.random.normal(size=1000), 10**(np.random.normal(size=1000)+1)]).T

        self.mpl_canvas.ax.clear()

        self.mpl_canvas.ax.plot(mock_data[:, 0], mock_data[:, 1], 'o', label='Test sample')
        self.mpl_canvas.ax.set_xscale('log')
        self.mpl_canvas.ax.set_yscale('log')
        self.mpl_canvas.ax.set_xlim([1e-3, 1e3])
        self.mpl_canvas.ax.set_ylim([1e-2, 1e4])


        if not self.polygon is None:
            self.mpl_canvas.ax.plot([self.polygon[0], 1], [self.polygon[1], 1], marker='s', color='orange')
            
        self.mpl_canvas.draw()
        
    def handle_draw_polygon(self):
        self.gateEditor = polygonGateEditor(self.mpl_canvas.ax)
        self._disableInputForGate(True)
        self.mpl_canvas.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)

        self.gateEditor.draw_confirmed.connect(self.polygon_return)
        self.gateEditor.connectInputs()

    def polygon_return(self, vert, event_button):
        self._disableInputForGate(False)
        self.mpl_canvas.unsetCursor()

        button_name = 'right' if event_button == 3 else 'left'
        # This part of the code causes the bug:
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Message box', '{0} button input detected'.format(button_name))
        
        # If we comment out the above code and switch to the following code, bug goes away:
        # gateName = 'new gate' + str(np.random.random())
        
        self.polygon = vert
        self.mpl_canvas.ax.clear()
        self.draw_figure()

    def _disableInputForGate(self, disable=True):
        self.loadDataPB.setEnabled(not disable)
        self.addGatePB.setEnabled(not disable)

class plotCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.fig.set_layout_engine("tight") 
        super().__init__(self.fig)

        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.draw()


class polygonGateEditor(QtCore.QObject):

    draw_confirmed = QtCore.Signal(object, int)

    def __init__(self, ax) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.ax = ax
        self.canvas = self.ax.figure.canvas
        self.background = None

        self.pressCid, self.releaseCid = (0 ,0)

        self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax.bbox)
        self.line = matplotlib.lines.Line2D([], [], marker='s', color='r', animated=True)

        self.line.set_data([], [])
        self.ax.add_line(self.line)
        self.blitDraw()

    def addGate_on_press(self, event):
        if event.button == 1 or event.button == 3:
            vert = np.array([event.xdata, event.ydata])

            self.draw_confirmed.emit(vert, event.button)
            self.disconnectInputs()
            self.blitDraw()


    def addGate_on_motion(self, event):
        self.line.set_data([event.xdata, 1], [event.ydata, 1])
        self.blitDraw()

    def connectInputs(self):
        self.pressCid = self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.addGate_on_press)
        self.moveCid = self.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.addGate_on_motion)

    def disconnectInputs(self):
        self.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.pressCid)
        self.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.moveCid)

    def blitDraw(self):
        self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
        self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = mainUi()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())



I don't seem to be able to reproduce the issue, but the procedure is a bit convoluted and I strongly believe it can be minimized. I'd suggest you to take your time to reduce the code to a more appropriate [mre] (for instance, if you do believe that the issue is within the dialog alone, then there's probably no point in providing code to create a polygon and ask us to do it).

@musicamante Thanks I guess you're right. Now reduced further.

The static QMessageBox functions call exec. Presumably, you also used exec when testing with QDialog. It seems this may interfere with the context-menu opened by the right-click, since this will start a local event-loop. If you comment out the code that creates the context-menu action, does this change the behaviour?

@ekhumoro I agree with your reasoning. I also suspected the mouse event was not full handled by neither of the loops. But no, get ride of the context menu does not fix the bug.

OK, I am answering my own question here, just in case anyone step over this in the future.
The workaround: when connecting the click event to function, use the button_release_event instead of button_press_event.
def connectInputs(self):
        self.pressCid = self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.addGate_on_press)
        self.moveCid = self.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.addGate_on_motion)

This is not a perfect solution as it changes the behaviors slightly, but it works. The reason why this works is the following:
When the user right clicks or ctrl-click on the canvas, three events was passed to the widget, in this particular order: MouseButtonPress -> ContextMenu -> MouseButtonRelease. (You can install event filter to check that). But if the dialog is generated after the press event and gains the focus/modality, the canvas widget will only receive the first two event. I am not sure why it can actually receive the 2nd event, or not receiving the release event freeze it. But for all the purpose of this app, trigger the logic/dialog on release solve the problem.
Yes, it is also a mystery to me why ctrl-click does not suffer the same bug.
